# How to json_encode array with french accents?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, json

I have an array item with a French accent ([WIPDescription] => Recette  Soupe à lOignon Sans Boeuf US).  The data is being properly pulled from the database (mysql).

However, when I try to encode this as json using the php built in json_encode it produces a null json value (OS X server: php 5.3.4, json 1.2.1  enabled).

In a Linux server, the description is cut off after the first accent character.

I tried all the json_encode options with no success.  Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`json_encode`  only wants `utf-8`. Depending on your character set, you can use `iconv` or [`utf8_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) *before* calling `json_encode` on your variable. Probably with `array_walk_recursive`.

As requested, an **unfinished** way to alter an array, with the assumptions that (1) it doesn't contain objects, and (2) the array keys are in ascii / lower bounds, so can be left as is:

```
$current_charset = 'ISO-8859-15';//or what it is now
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$value) use ($current_charset){
     $value = iconv('UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$current_charset,$value);

});
```

Comment: array_walk_recursive requires a user-defined function. Would you suggest he make one which literally calls utf8_encode on each value? If so how would that affect the actual array values - would they be returned or passed by reference? This sounds like a great idea I just can't put it together in my head.

Comment: @Matt Anderson: OK, just this once... I'll edit in an example that doesn't work on objects, but will work on arrays, and assumes the keys are ascii (=valid in ascii/ISO-8859-*/utf-8).

Comment: The database collation and character set is set as utf8_unicode_ci.  How do I determine the character set of the mysql returned array?

Comment: Thank you.  When I used mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $Connection); it works fine.  (I do realize that I have to use the  mysql_set_character_set() function to properly do this.)

Comment: @Natkeeran: indeed, would work too, and I always use the query-variant (especially in PDO), I see no reason why `mysql_set_charset` would be better. Granted, the manual does state it, but I have yet to find a reason why.

Comment: @Wrikken Hi i have username coming from database if simple echo it everything is fine it prints `诶ó` but after putting it in array and json_encode it becomes `\u8bf6\u00f3`. I'm really stuck in it can you please help? i have tried iconv it makes the username empty.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: Isn't that just the representation in unicode in json? I'm not necessarily seeing a problem here.

Comment: so you mean the unicode is automatically converted by html? also what about if i'm accessing the data via a webservice in mobile client? is it still OK? @Wrikken

Answer (score 61):

I found this to be the easiest way to deal with it

```
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - makes is readable
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - encodes characters correctly
JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - gets rid of escape slash '\'
also notice that these option are separated by a pipe '|'

Comment: exactly what I needed!

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE is the option to use when retrieving utf-8 strings from a database ; it solved my problem when trying encoding only replaced special chars with '?'.

Comment: You are my hero! :D

Comment: It might help to set the charset while connecting to the database too. `new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME .';charset=utf8mb4`

Answer (score 12):

Another solution would be to use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php) or [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) before using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) to pass the encoded char

like this:

```
   $array = array('myvalue' => utf8_encode('ééàà'));
   return json_encode($array);
```

Or using `htmlentities` :

```
   $array = array('myvalue' => htmlentities('ééàà'));
   return json_encode($array);
```

Comment: And when in the browser how to decode back to utf8?

Comment: @Inanikian Using PHP `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and HTML `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: I tried `header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8')` but still have the code u/... So I decided to remove the french word `à`...

Comment: This solved my problem with json_encoding a string with ó in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
<? 

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE...");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $output[]=array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you deal with diacritics you can also add JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR and it will remove only the problems and leave the rest intact. I used utf_encode before I found this but it was messing up diacritics.

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = utf8_encode($string);

$json = json_decode($json);
```