# Accented letters with PHP: htmlentities and json_encode

Tags: php, html, json, html-entities

In my PHP webservice I have to return some arrays containing strings with accented letters  in JSON format (I parse them in my client app with JS).

But the `htmlentities` function replaces the strings containing accented letters with empty strings! If I don't use `htmlentities`, I get an error on `json_encode`.

```
$a = array('key' => 'èàìòù');
foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    $a[$k] = htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');

json_encode($a);
```

I also tried the `ENT_COMPAT` option, but I get only empty values.

Note that if I print my array with `print_r` before `htmlentities`, the content is ok.

More information:

Every file is in UTF-8 w/o BOM format (saved with Notepad++).
I already tried to add the headers to set UTF-8 in my PHP and HTML.
The DB table is in utf8_unicode_ci format.

Versions: PHP 5.3.3, MySQL 5.5.30-1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What about _not_ using `htmlentities`? I believe `é` is converted to `\u00e9` by `json_encode`, why not use that?

Comment: What happens if you just use $a[$k] = htmlentities($v); ?

Comment: Those should all get converted automatically in `json_encode`. Proof: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p0t-74w

Comment: To be perfectly clear: there is no need to run `htmlentities()` on data before `json_encode()` ing it.

Comment: `$a = array('key' =>  utf8_encode('èàìòù'));
$t= json_encode($a);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($t)); echo "</pre>";`

Please see the 3rd answer below accepted answer of the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928982/how-to-json-encode-array-with-french-accents given by @sdespont

Comment: I get an error encoding JSON, because the "è" character is converted to "Ã¨". If i don't use `htmlentities` at all, the "è" character is converted to "\u00e8" and I get an error again. I use jQuery with the $.getJSON method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying *which* error you are getting in `json_encode()`, but my suspicion is that your incoming data is not UTF-8 encoded, which will break both the unnecessary `htmlentities()` call (which you are instructing to expect UTF-8 data) and `json_encode()` (because that function requires all input data to be UTF-8).

Make sure the data you are encoding is actually UTF-8 encoded. You won't be needing `htmlentites()` at all then.

You're not saying where the data comes from, but if it's from a database, the *connection* sometimes needs to be explicitly set to UTF-8. See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: +1 Is exactly what I thought, perhaps a `utf8_encode($json)` would help

Comment: I think the server-side problem is now solved, specifing mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8') just as you suggested!

Comment: PS: I still need to call `htmlentities`, or the `JSON.parse` in my client app fails.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Marco you're welcome. `htmlentities()` shouldn't be necessary there, either, but I guess that's a different can of worms!

Comment: Yes, you're right: I understood that problem. I was using the JSONP callback in a wrong way, not passing the data as object but as string (!)