# json_encode not working on PDO fetched data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm hanging dry here. The user clicks on an option on a select list, then jQuery sends an xhr to the server to process, nothing special here, code works perfectly (firebug shows correct Posted data).

Then a simple code to return rows from a database where `W_id == $val`, and then fetch results in `$result`, then echo results as a json response:

```
public function getCities($val) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM cities WHERE w_id = :w_id");
    $sth->execute(array(':w_id' => $val));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($result);
    header("content-type:application/json");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Firebug shows the Post data but no Response. But when I uncomment the `print_r`, it shows me an array as a Response:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1401
        [name] => Aïn Bouchekif
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [id] => 1402
        [name] => Aïn Deheb
    )

    [2] => Array(
        [id] => 1403
        [name] => Aïn El Hadid
    ) and so on...
```

Which means that there are results that can be returned, but I don't know how to jsonify them. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: does it print anything if you skip the header?

Comment: Try `echo json_last_error()` after  `echo json_encode($result)`

Comment: I think, that problem in wrong headers. Try to check http request/response headers fully.

Comment: are you using a php framework?

Comment: if not, check how the method is being used, perhaps replace echo with return and then: echo getCities($val)

Comment: Same problem if I skip the header. I'm using my own work, no framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:
[UTF-8 character encoding battles json_encode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790027/utf-8-character-encoding-battles-json-encode)

```
public function getCities($val) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM cities WHERE w_id = :w_id");
    $sth->execute(array(':w_id' => $val));

    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    $rows = array();

    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

I found other answer here [How to json_encode array with french accents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928982/how-to-json-encode-array-with-french-accents) but keeps getting notices, illegal character found.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an encoding problem, you can verify this idea by using [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). You can add `charset=utf-8` to the header :

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print_r($result);
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); // <-- Here
echo json_encode($result);
echo json_last_error(); // <-- Here
```

Comment: With echo json_last_error(); success method is fired up, and I have 5 as a Response. Manual says it's Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded, I guess it's because of the ï