# Can't View data retrieved from MYSQL which is converted into JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am like to view the data retrieved by the SQL statement but when doing it only
**json_response** **display the data** but what I want to see is echo json_encode($json_response) format of data.
I follow this tutorial but did not get the same result.
**json_encode($json_response**) **shows no data AKA plain screen**
http://www.webslesson.info/2016/05/convert-data-from-mysql-to-json-formate-using-php.html

```
$query = "SELECT * from LibraryEvents";

  $result = mysqli_query($connDB,$query);

  $json_response = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json_response[] = $row;
        //array_push($json_response,$row_array);
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($json_response);
  echo '<pre>';
  echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: So, what's the output you see?

Comment: print_r($json_response) show all data but echo json_encode($json_response) show no data

Comment: do you have any data inserted in LibraryEvents table ?

Comment: There is data since I did say print_r display data but json_encode does not display anything

Comment: $connDB = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");
its your $connDB is right ?

Comment: Yes. I have tested the database which should not be the problem since **print_r display data** but **json_encode does not display anything**. https://i.imgur.com/NQiJkgv.jpg

Comment: The problem currently is json_encode does not show any anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frequenty, this is due to your response having accents: if your response has accents (é, à, etc.), json_encode will not work properly.

This might help you: [How to json_encode array with french accents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928982/how-to-json-encode-array-with-french-accents)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer solve the problem. After changing word with accent, it solved everything.