# PHP json_decode() with accents doesn't work

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array that saves some accented characters in it, a value could be `üna`. Saving this as JSON i use `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` which works correctly, however when trying to display on the page with `json_decode()` it will not show because of the accent.

```
$arr = json_decode($array, true);
print_r($arr);
```

I have tried adding the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to that aswell as adding a UTF-8 header line but nothing will print out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to json\_encode array with french accents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928982/how-to-json-encode-array-with-french-accents)

Answer (score 1):

JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE Encodes multibyte Unicode characters literally, this will do it

```
$arr=array("üna","&8*");
$encode_json = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($encode_json);
$decode_json=json_decode($encode_json);
print_r($decode_json);
```

Comment: When trying this with my array, the accent comes out as `u00c3u00bc` so doesn't work correctly

Comment: @BrendanMullan it looks ok to me: https://eval.in/999371 . Perhaps your page isn't set up for UTF8. Make sure your page starts something like `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>` - see https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations